# TouchXML (Sudzc) and using this data properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, ios, xcode

I am using Sudzc (it uses TouchXML) for parsing my web services WSDL, now I am using multiple web services with almost the same WSDL definitions. I edited my code to use this, this is what happens:

```
CXMLNode* element = [[Soap getNode: [doc rootElement] withName: @"Body"] childAtIndex:0];
output = [Soap deserialize:element];
```

And the soap deserialize is as following:

```
// Deserialize an object as a generic object
+ (id) deserialize: (CXMLNode*) element{
      return [element stringValue];
}
```

I get data back ilke this when I log it:

```
{
    RetrieveSetResult =     {
        Entities =         {
            RequestData =             {
                AccountCode =                 {
                    IsDirty = false;
                    IsNothing = true;
                    NoRights = false;
                    Value = "<null>";
                };
                AccountContactEmail =                 {
                    IsDirty = false;
                    IsNothing = true;
                    NoRights = false;
                    Value = "<null>";
                };
            };
        };
        SessionID = 40;
    };
}
```

How can I use this data in a user friendly way, so i want to be able to say which field I want to select and read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try access them like a dictionary

```
NSDictionary *dic = [myXMLparsedObject valueForKey:@"RetrieveSetResult"];
int sesID = [[dic valueForKey:@"SessionID"] intValue];
NSDictionary *entis = [dic valueForKey:@"Entities"];
// … and so on
```

looping through all elements:

```
// for iOS prior 4.0
NSArray *dicKeys = [xmlDic allKeys];
for (NSString *key in dicKeys) {
    id obj = [xmlDic valueForKey:key];
}

// way simpler in > 4.0
[xmlDic enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

}];
```

in both cases you can access each `key` and `obj` value ;)

Comment: This is going the good direction, how could i loop trough all of the fields in requestData without knowing which fields are in here?

Comment: NSDictionary *dic = [value valueForKey:@"RetrieveSetResult"];
    NSString *sesId = [dic valueForKey:@"SessionID"];
    NSDictionary *entis = [dic valueForKey:@"Entities"];
    NSDictionary *reqd = [entis valueForKey:@"RequestData"];
    
    for(NSDictionary *data in reqd) {
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", [data valueForKey:@"Value"]);
    }

--- Doesn't work!

Comment: It returns null to a selector if SoapRequest.m:connectionDidFinishLoading looking for "Body". But if I write "soap:Body" it works great! How would I append this "soap" prefix, is it namespace or something?
Thanks for the answer relikd, @Wesso!